# Which sensors can run in the background in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, hardware, sensors

I'm doing research for my company as we consider how to make our app work on iPhone. I'm looking for a list of iPhone sensors/measurement tools that can run *in the background at the command of an app.* Internet searches are not proving helpful, so I'm turning to the experts here.
I'd like to know if the following iPhone features in particular can be run in the background of the phone via an app:

- Hall Sensor (used for electronic compass)
- Proximity Sensor
- Motion Sensor/Accelerometer
- Gyroscope
- Frequency Sensor
- IR (infrared)
- GPS
- Camera
- Microphone
- Ambient Light Sensor

Again, I want to know if these features can be activated by an app to run in the background of the phone. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are 5 kinds of apps that are an exception to the rule:

**Audio**: Allowing users to use radio apps like Pandora, InstaCast in the background while they’re using iPhone’s Safari browser to surf the web etc.
**VoIP**: This will allow VoiP apps like Skype to run in the background so that it users can receive and make calls even when they’re running in the background.
**Location**: Apps that need to constantly track your GPS coordinates can now run in the background while you listen to music or surf the internet.
Newsstand apps that are downloading new content.
Apps that receive continuous updates from an external accessory in the Background.

Comment: I'm a little confused, what rule? Does that mean that those are the only features that can be run in the background?

Comment: See the Apple App submission guidelines. I would link it, but it's not a lot of use without a ADC iOS account.